# Performing Logistic Regression with a large number of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression, prediction

I have a dataset with 330 samples and 27 features for each sample, with a binary class problem for Logistic Regression.

According to the "rule if ten" I need at least 10 events for each feature to be included. Though, I have an imbalanced dataset, with 20% o positive class and 80% of negative class.

That gives me only 70 events, allowing approximately only 7/8 features to be included in the Logistic model.

I'd like to evaluate all the features as predictors, I don't want to hand pick any features.

So what would you suggest? Should I make all possible 7 features combinations? Should I evaluate each feature alone with an association model and then pick only the best ones for a final model?

I'm also curious about the handling of categorical and continuous features, can I mix them? If I have a categorical [0-1] and a continuous [0-100], should I normalize?

Comment: you can actually post this question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe this one was already asked there, but did not receive much attention. This isn't enough of a good reason to replicate it here anyway. The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your best choice would be to use L1 regularized logistic regression (aka Lasso regression). In case you're not familiar with it, the algorithm automatically selects some of the features by penalizing those that do not lead to increased accuracy (in layman terms).

You can increase/decrease this regularization strength (it's just a parameter) till your model achieved the highest accuracy (or some other metric) on a test set or in a cross-validation procedure.

Comment: Hi Stergios, in this case I would like to stick with the standard Logistic Regression for research reasons, but I will included LASSO in my future experiments. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find the 7/8 features that give the highest accuracy? If so, you could potentially look at all possible combinations (although this may bee too expensive in resources and time). Or you could run the LASSO and let it select the best features. Then run the standard Log. Reg. using only those features. However, this is like using any feature selection method.

Comment: I'd like to see how all the features relate to outcome, but I don't want to use anything but Logistic Regression. If I had enough events I would just feed all the features to the model, but unfortunately I don't have. I want to use Logistic Regression because this is the standard approach used and I need this as a comparison measure.